# Unable to access methods inside the jest testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am unable to access these API methods inside the testing file. Please help me understand. And I don't wanna change the implementation code in **SampleReact.js**. Please note it is as

```
**FileName SampleReact.js**

import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';

export const SamplePageComponent = (props) => {

const [sampleValue, setSampleValue] = useState({});

const FetchSampleAPI = async () => {
    return axios.get('sample/api').then((resp) => {
        setSampleValue(resp.data);      
        Promise.resolve(resp.data);
    });
};

}



**FileName SampleReact.test.js**

import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import {SamplePageComponent} from '../../SamplePageComponent';


test("illustrate spy",  async () => {
    // arrange
    const {SamplePageComponent} = require('../../SamplePageComponent')
    
    // act
    let result  = await SamplePageComponent().FetchSampleAPI(); // Gives Error and unable to access function
    
    // assert
    expect(result.Name).toEqual("Hello");

})
```

Comment: I think you are looking to mock the API request. Those methods wont exist nor are they "methods". The react component will call that api and you will have a mock in place that fills in some prefabricated data for you. https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/node

Comment: I am planning to test the API method FetchSampleAPI. I am not able to access that method

Comment: You don't test it by calling it directly, even if you could (you can't, it's not a method or even property of the component, just a nested function). You test it by simulating iteration with the component that leads to it being invoked, and asserting on the side effect.